Black Screen Issue During Ubuntu Installation
When I try to install Ubuntu on my system, whether CSM is enabled or disabled, the screen stays black. Because of this, is there a way to compile and install Ubuntu on the system with the Nvidia driver, or is there another solution?
my system is:
r5 5600
rtx 3060

This question is similar to: Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu offers a number of products (for Servers, Desktops & flavors) but you've not said which you were attempting to install. They use different installers & we don't yet know which you attempted; nor as some releases have multiple choices (older, newer) we don't know if those choices apply to you or what you used.  Given your lack of detail, I'll suggest trying a later release, or later kernel stack of your chosen release (if you're using an older ISO; eg. 5 kernels are available on ISOs for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop selected by ISO downloaded)
